# floor(24.24*1e4) returns wrong value

Tags: php, floor

Performing some coordinates rounding, I came to some bug or something, with different numbers it works as I needed

```
$res = floor(24.24*1e4)/1e4;
echo $res;
```

returns 24.2399

Do You know what is so special with this 242400, that it's returns 242399?

Comment: I think it's a "binary representation".

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The problem is related to floating point precision**

Even though the PHP manual says "Returns the next lowest integer value by rounding down value if necessary." if you read further down the page for "return values" in the  PHP manual for [floor()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php) you'll see:

> **value** rounded to the next lowest *integer*. The return value of `floor()`
> is still of type [float](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php) because the value range of float is usually
> bigger than that of integer.

When we checkout [float](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php) types we see a warning:

> Floating point numbers have limited precision. Although it depends on
> the system, PHP typically uses the IEEE 754 double precision format,
> which will give a maximum relative error due to rounding in the order
> of 1.11e-16. Non elementary arithmetic operations may give larger
> errors, and, of course, error propagation must be considered when
> several operations are compounded.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is due to float value, sometimes it happens.

Have you tried this?

```
$res = floor((int)(24.24*1e4))/1e4;
echo $res;
```

**Or** you can use round with an optional parameter to round up at a specific decimal.

For your example :

```
round($res, 4)
```

Comment: `$res = floor((int)(24.24*1e4))/1e4;` returns 24.2399 you can try http://writecodeonline.com/php/  .
for me worked:
    `floor(strval(24.24*1e4))/1e4;`

Comment: solution `floor(strval(24.24*1e4))/1e4` for number 23.0266 dosn't work :(  in this case i used: `floor(strval(24.0266+0.0000000001)*1e4)/1e4;` :D